# Not able to set imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I Initialise the imageview using

`iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPic);`

After which the camera takes the pic . In `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` method , I am doing the following to set the ImageView .

```
Bitmap bmpEmail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());
iv.setImageBitmap(bmpEmail);
```

I am just getting a a blank screen. ALso the layout of the screen when the app , launches is like this:
[image]

AFter I take the pic , the screen gets distorted, I have no idea why this is happening .

[image]

PS: I have increased the size of the second picture , so that the buttons are visible, If you see the size of the buttons has reduced quite a bit and Imageview placeholder seems to be taking up most of the screenspace without showing a imageview as such.

I have posted my XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_weight="60"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="Email Pic"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you get bitmap in bmpEmail??

Comment: Yes I am getting that value `bmpEmail >>android.graphics.Bitmap@410b8760`

Comment: because your decoded bitmap size is large and your `ImageView` is of height `wrap_content`, so the size increases. Either give fix size or use `layout_weight` to format it properly.

Comment: cant you try the same with a relative layout? At times weights do distort screens. And for small screen devices the result may turn out to be unexpected.

Comment: What is out referring to?

Comment: @JoxTraex `File out = new File(fileUri.getPath());`

Comment: @RaviBhatt MAte can you provide any examples or documentation related to the same?

Comment: @RaviBhatt Can you please post that as an answer. I will accept the the same. I fugured out how to do that .

Comment: @misguided have pasted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because your decoded bitmap size is large and your `ImageView` is of height `wrap_content`, so the size increases. Either give fix size or use `layout_weight` to format it properly.

Comment: Not the exact answer I was looking for. but had enough pointers to turn me in the correct directions.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibPic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bPic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email Pic"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Mate can't see the imageview yet. But the buttons layout doesn't change now onload of app and after taking pics

Comment: It looks like this now `http://imgur.com/FwHBJkH` (click on the link to view the layout)

Answer (score 0):

As Ravi bhatt suspected this was an issue with the bitmap image size. I got the size using :

`bmpEmail.getHeight()` & `bmpEmail.getWidth()`

Used the following method to get ImageView size:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto1.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        Log.d("Test", "Height: " + iv.getMeasuredHeight() + " Width: " + iv.getMeasuredWidth());
                        return true;
                      }
                  });
```

Finally scaled the image down , using the following

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpEmail, 512, 540, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

The display works fine now.